# How to split an area into given tiles?

Tags: javascript, html, math

Say I have a div 660x480px where I want to have x number of tiles which I find from a server side generated list. So if the list has 9 elements I want to place 9 tiles over this div. How can I calculate this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to split up 660px in 9 tiles that are all the same width? I don't really get this question. Mind filling it out some more?

Comment: It could be 9 or 15 or 30 tiles. But all must have the same width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use the space as efficiently as possible. Than, it sounds more like a mathematical problem. One solution is proposed in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx). I think it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a bit lazy, you don't need to calculate anything at all:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

If you want to do it yourself, width wise it can be simple enough if you set a certain width and height for tiles, but I am not sure what content your tiles hold and of what sizes they can be, so it will be difficult to tell you how to tackle the problem the best way.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because the masonry plugin is just arrangeing the tiles in vertical columns first when css arrange it horizontal. In the masonry plugin you have to define the column width.